# Can't get rid of the C++ warning

Tags: c++, types, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am new to C++ and this warning has been driving me crazy.

> Warning   C4244   'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data at line 41

The line is:

```cpp
((x == 1) || (x == -1)) ? (result == sum(coeff, size, x)) : (true);
```

I have checked my code, it seems consistent with types (as far as I'm concerned). I have cleared/rebuild solutions, restarted VS a couple of times.

By simply removing parts of the line, the issue seems to be here:

```
(result == sum(coeff, size, x)
```

When I replace it with anything else, the warning goes away. I have no other warning besides this one.

Is there a nuance I am not understanding?

Here is my full code:

```cpp
int main() {

    double x = -1;
    const size_t size = 4;
    double coeff[size] = {0};
    cout << Horner(coeff, size, x);

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

void fillArray(double* coeff, size_t size)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    double lower_bound = 0;
    double upper_bound = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        coeff[i] = (rand() % 2001 - 1000) / 100.0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Coefficients: " << coeff[i] << " " << endl;
    }
    return;
}
double sum(double* coeff, size_t size, int sign)
{
    size_t s = size;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
        if (s % 2 == 1 || sign == 1) {
            sum = sum + coeff[i];
        } else sum = sum - coeff[i];
        s--;
    }
    return sum; //sum is accurately calculated for x = -1 and x = 1
}
double Horner(double* coeff, size_t size, double x)
{
    fillArray(coeff, size);
    double term = coeff[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        term = coeff[i + 1] + term * x;
    }

    double result = term;
    ((x == 1) || (x == -1)) ? (result == sum(coeff, size, x)) : (true);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using `true` as double looks suspicious. `((x == 1) || (x == -1)) ? (result == sum(coeff, size, x)) : (true);` - unjustified use of the ternary operator.

Comment: In addition to the above ... you aren't actually assigning it anywhere :) The result of that ternary-if is discarded

Comment: Did you mean to *assign* the return value of `sum()` to `result`? `==` is a *comparison*. Perhaps you meant `double result = ((x == 1) || (x == -1)) ? sum(coeff, size, x) : term;` instead?

Comment: On a side note: `for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) { term = coeff[i + 1] + term * x; }` can be written nicer as `for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) { term = coeff[i] + term * x; }` instead

Comment: *"because it is just a comparison"*  Oh, so another reason not to write code like that. It totally tricked me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `Horner` is

```
double Horner(double* coeff, size_t size, double x)
```

which takes `double x` as the third parameter. The definition of `sum` is

```
double sum(double* coeff, size_t size, int sign)
```

which takes an `int` as the third parameter.

Since you're passing in `x` (which is a `double`) in `Horner` to `sum`, there's a `double` to `int` type conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! The warning is fixed now

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a nuance I am not understanding?

The cuase of the compiler warning is in the use of `x` in the call to `sum`:

```
sum(coeff, size, x)
//              ^^^
```

You can remove that warning by using a variable of type `int` and setting its value appropriately.

```
int sign = static_cast<int>(x);
```

and then use `sum(coeff, size, sign)`

You may also inline the `static_cast`. Use `sum(coeff, size, static_cast<int>(x))`.

### Disclaimer

There are other logic issues in the posted code that you may want to address separately.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please point me at those issues

Comment: @Nadia, the second comment by Remy Lebeau describes the problem I was thinking of.